# How to format text in a textarea for blog/news article

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've designed a basic blog app using php. For the entry, I've used a html form and used < textarea > for the main article of the blog. All works fine. The data is saved to a database and called up by other pages.

However, I'd like to be able to add formatting to this so other users who don't know to wrap tags around things can also post an entry. The type of thing I'm after is pretty much EXACTLY what is used here to post replies etc.

I'm guessing this would be either Javascript or php, but I don't have a clue how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are looking for a `web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG editor`, like

- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)
- among many others...

Here you have a few ones:

- [10 best WYSIWYG Text and HTML Editors for Your Next Project](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/)
- [15 Really Useful Web-based HTML Editors](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-really-useful-web-based-html-editors/)
- [Google: Javascript HTML WYSIWYG](https://www.google.es/search?q=Javascript+HTML+WYSIWYG&oq=Javascript+HTML+WYSIWYG&aqs=chrome.0.57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks gmo and @Kautil. Look exactly what I need. I'll have a play about with these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ckeditor or tiny mce editor